# Spring project using LOG4J works in tomcat but not in JBoss7

Tags: spring, jboss, log4j

I have a Spring Webflow project that use LOG4J for logging.. The project works under Tomcat but once I move the project to JBoss AS7. I don't get any log files or the logging to the console?

Comment: did you read this ? http://docs.jboss.org/process-guide/en/html/logging.html

Comment: yes... and I don't see how this will help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to remove the log4j dependency from your deployment or [exclude](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/How+To#HowTo-HowdoIuselog4j.propertiesorlog4j.xmlinsteadofusingtheloggingsubsystemconfiguration%3F) the servers log4j library and use the one packaged in your deployment.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.jboss.org/process-guide/en/html/logging.html chapter 10.3 says on the first line:

> The **log4j** configuration is **loaded from** the jboss server **conf/log4j.xml**
>   file.

Then further down there are individual chapters for

> Using your own log4j.xml file

10.3.3ff. I can't tell you which one of those applies.

Comment: This is not for JBoss As 7. JBoss AS 7 does not use log4j as it's log manager.

Comment: Arrgg, I'm a fool, sorry. It's been too long since I last worked with JBoss on a daily basis.